# UI Record Counter of closed activities in ms crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am  trying to make an UI Record Counter of the Closed Activities showing the count of open activities.

My list of parameters is:

```
['navActivities:activitypointer:regardingobjectid','navActivityHistory:activitypointer:regardingobjectid']
```

Has anyone figured out the **"Closed Activity"** showing the same amount as **"Activities"** I seem to be getting the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue. Gayan Perera will release a update. See in comments of this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/gayanperera/archive/2012/12/17/dynamics-crm-2011-navigation-ui-record-counter.aspx).